# 403 Forbidden Error from AWS API Gateway when accessing through NGINX Reverse Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-api-gateway, reverse-proxy, aws-application-load-balancer

***Issue is solved. View comments for detailed information***

I have configured the NGINX reverse proxy to route traffic to an AWS API Gateway Endpoint but it continue to throw 403 Forbidden error. AWS API Gateway execution logs doesn't show that request coming towards the AWS API Gateway either. No blocking at the WAF level as well. Simply it seems the error is coming from the CloudFront level.

My Deployment flow is as follows

Client > NGINX ALB > NGINX EC2 (Reverse Proxy) > AWS API GW Endpoint

My NGINX Configuration

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name xxxxxxx.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /path/to/key;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

        ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=63072000;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

        default_type "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";

        location / {
            set $upstream_endpoint xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
            resolver 169.254.169.253;
            proxy_set_header Host 'xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
            proxy_pass https://$upstream_endpoint;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }
}
```

I have even tried changing the ALB HTTPS Listener security policy to see whether its related to TLS version, but no luck.

**EDIT - Additional Information**

- I have configured the DNS mapping as a CNAME for xxxxxxx.example.com
  to public DNS of my ALB in Route53.
- **This setup works as expected when I directly route traffic to an EC2
  instance running the NGINX server proxy rather than the ALB.**

***Issue is solved. View comments for detailed information***

Comment: Are you able to `curl` to your endpoint? What authentication settings does the API have on the tested endpoints ( IAM or cognito authorizer, lambda authorizer or no auth)? Does rhe API have an access policy configured?

Comment: Yes it is perfectly accessible with the API GW URL directly. No authorisers configured, only requiring API key. Its sent in the header with x-api-key headers

Comment: @LRutten I was able to figure this out. It was a silly mistake from my part related to a WAF rule. WAF configured for the API GW was blocking requests originating through my proxy server to the API GW as it was violating AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList - HostingProviderIPList rule set. Allowing my proxy server IP traffic in WAF solved the issue. Thanks!